# How to repopulate a linked list to a file in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct NodeT_
{
    char name[30], lastName[20];
    int year;
    char id[30];
    int randomID;
    float average;
    char email[30];
    char mobile[15], ppsn[10];
    struct NodeT_* NEXT;
}node;

void addElementAttheEnd(node* top, char studentID[]);
void addElementAttheStart(node** top, char studentID[]);
void display(node* top);
void displayToFile(node* top);
int search(node* top, char searchID[]);
int location(node* top, char searchID[]);
int length(node* top);
void deleteAtEnd(node* top);
void deleteAtStart(node** top);
void deleteintheMiddle(node* top, char searchID[]);
void deletedAtLocation(node* top, int loc);
void updateNodeValues(node* top, char ID[]);

int main()
{
    node* HEAD = NULL;
    node* temp;
    node* temp2;
    int option;
    int searchNum;
    int result;
    char searchTerm[20];
    int foundLocation;
    FILE* inp;
    node fileValue;


    /** Repopulate the linked list based on the file **/
    inp = fopen("list.txt", "r");

    if (inp == NULL)
        printf("Sorry the file could not be opened\n");
    else
    {
        while (!feof(inp))
        {
            result = fscanf(inp, "%s %s %s %f  %s", fileValue.ppsn, fileValue.name, fileValue.lastName, &fileValue.year, fileValue.email);

            if (result == 5)
            {
                printf("%s %s %s %d %s\n", fileValue.ppsn, fileValue.name, fileValue.lastName, fileValue.year, fileValue.email);
                //Add the fileValue data to the list
            }

        }

        fclose(inp);
    }
```

> So above is the code I'm using to repopulate the linked list with the file and im getting no errors at all but for some reason when I run it its giving me an exception thrown I'd like an example of how to fix it or if you can explain to me where I'm going wrong that would be very helpful cheers. The end result is for it to repopulate the entered data into a file accordingly.

```
    printf("1) Add customer(Note: PPS Number must be unique).\n");
    printf("2) Display all customer details to screen\n");
    printf("3) Display Customer Details\n");
    printf("4) Update a Customer Details\n");
    printf("5) Delete Customer\n");
    printf("6) Generate statistics(a – e) based on the user selecting a booking type\n");
    printf("7) Print all customer details into a report file.\n");
    printf("8) List all the customers in order of year born :\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while (option != -1)
    {

        if (option == 1)
        {
            printf("Please the new student ID\n");
            scanf("%s", searchTerm);

            if (HEAD == NULL)
                addElementAttheStart(&HEAD, searchTerm);
            else
            {
                result = location(HEAD, searchTerm);
                if (result == -1)
                    addElementAttheEnd(HEAD, searchTerm);
                else
                    printf("Sorry this student already exists\n");
            }
        }

        else if (option == 2)
        {
            display(HEAD);
        }

        else if (option == 3)
        {
            if (HEAD == NULL)
                printf("Can not delete from an empty list\n");
            else if (HEAD->NEXT == NULL)
                deleteAtStart(&HEAD);
            else
                deleteAtEnd(HEAD);
        }

        else if (option == 4)
        {
            printf("Please enter the search ID\n");
            scanf("%s", searchTerm);

            updateNodeValues(HEAD, searchTerm);
        }

        /*else if (option == 4)
        {
            display(HEAD);
        }*/

        else if (option == 5)
        {
            if (HEAD == NULL)
                printf("Can not delete from an empty list\n");
            else if (HEAD->NEXT == NULL)
                deleteAtStart(&HEAD);
            else
                deleteAtEnd(HEAD);
        }

        else if (option == 6)
        {
            printf("Please enter the student ID you wish to search for\n");
            scanf("%s", searchTerm);

            result = location(HEAD, searchTerm);

            if (result == -1)
                printf("This student ID does not exist\n");
            else
                printf("This student was found at location %d\n", result);
        }

        else if (option == 7)
        {
            displayToFile(HEAD);
        }

        printf("1) Add customer(Note: PPS Number must be unique).\n");
        printf("2) Display all customer details to screen\n");
        printf("3) Display Customer Details\n");
        printf("4) Update a Customer Details\n");
        printf("5) Delete Customer\n");
        printf("6) Generate statistics(a – e) based on the user selecting a booking type\n");
        printf("7) Print all customer details into a report file.\n");
        printf("8) List all the customers in order of year born :\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
    }




}


void addElementAttheEnd(node* top, char studentID[])
{
    node* temp;
    node* temp2;

    //Creating the new node
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    //Reading in the data 
    printf("Please enter PPSN number\n");
    scanf("%s", &temp->ppsn);
    printf("Please enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%s", temp->name);
    printf("Please enter your surname\n");
    scanf("%s", &temp->lastName);
    //printf("Please enter your ID\n");
    //scanf("%s", temp->id);
    strcpy(temp->id, studentID);
    printf("Please enter the year you were born\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp->year);
    printf("Please enter your email\n");
    scanf("%s", temp->email);

    temp->NEXT = NULL;

    //Finding the last node
    temp2 = top;
    while (temp2->NEXT != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->NEXT;
    }

    temp2->NEXT = temp;
}

void addElementAttheStart(node** top, char studentID[])
{
    node* temp;

    //Creating the new node
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    //Reading in the data 
    printf("Please enter PPSN number\n");
    scanf("%s", &temp->ppsn);
    printf("Please enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%s", temp->name);
    printf("Please enter your surname\n");
    scanf("%s", &temp->lastName);
    //printf("Please enter your ID\n");
    //scanf("%s", temp->id);
    strcpy(temp->id, studentID);
    printf("Please enter the year you were born\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp->year);
    printf("Please enter your email\n");
    scanf("%s", temp->email);
    

    temp->NEXT = *top; //*top currently has the address of the first node 
    //in the list which become the second node when temp is added infront of it
    *top = temp;
}

void display(node* top)
{
    node* temp;
    if (top == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    else
    {
        temp = top;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            //Display payload data
            //Move to the next node

            printf("PPSN: %s Name: %s Surname:%s Year: %d Email %s\n", temp->ppsn, temp->name, temp->lastName, temp->year, temp->email);
            temp = temp->NEXT;
        }
    }
}

void displayToFile(node* top)
{
    FILE* outp;
    node* temp;

    if (top == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    else
    {
        temp = top;

        outp = fopen("List.txt", "w");

        if (outp == NULL)
            printf("Sorry the file could not be opened\n");

        else
        {
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                //Display payload data
                //Move to the next node

                fprintf(outp, "PPSN: %s Name: %s Lastname:%s Year: %d Email %s\n", temp->ppsn, temp->name, temp->lastName, temp->year, temp->email);
                temp = temp->NEXT;
            }

            fclose(outp);
        }
    }
}

int search(node* top, char searchID[])
{
    node* temp;


    if (top == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    else
    {
        temp = top;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            //Display payload data
            //Move to the next node
            if (strcmp(temp->id, searchID) == 0)
            {
                printf("Found the element");
                return 1;
            }

            temp = temp->NEXT;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int length(node* top)
{
    node* temp;
    int length = 0;

    if (top == NULL)
        return 0;

    else
    {
        temp = top;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            //Display payload data
            //Move to the next node
            length++;
            temp = temp->NEXT;
        }

    }

    return length;
}

void deleteAtEnd(node* top)
{
    node* last;
    node* secondlast{};

    last = top;

    while (last->NEXT != NULL)
    {
        secondlast = last;
        last = last->NEXT;
    }

    secondlast->NEXT = NULL;
    free(last);
}
void deleteAtStart(node** top)
{
    node* temp;

    temp = *top;
    *top = temp->NEXT;
    free(temp);

}
void deleteintheMiddle(node* top, char searchID[])
{
    node* last;
    node* secondlast{};
    int searchNumber;
    int removed = 0;

    last = top;



    while (last->NEXT != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(last->id, searchID) == 0)
        {
            //This is the node to remove...
            secondlast->NEXT = last->NEXT;
            free(last);
            removed = 1;
            break;
        }

        secondlast = last;
        last = last->NEXT;
    }

    if (removed == 0)
    {
        printf("The node could not be found\n");
    }
}

void updateNodeValues(node* top, char ID[])
{
    node* temp;
    int search = 0;
    temp = top;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->id, ID) == 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter a new integer and string for the ID\n");

            //Reading in the data
            printf("Please enter your ppsn\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->ppsn);
            printf("Please enter your first name\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->name);
            printf("Please enter you lastname\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->lastName);
            printf("Please enter the year you were born\n");
            scanf("%f", &temp->year);
            printf("Please enter your email\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->email);

            search = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (search == 0)
        printf("The value of the ID was never found\n");
}

int location(node* top, char searchID[20])
{
    node* temp;
    int location = -1;
    int i = 1;

    temp = top;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->id, searchID) == 0)
        {
            location = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
        temp = temp->NEXT;
    }

    return location;
}

void deletedAtLocation(node* top, int loc)
{
    node* temp;
    node* prevTemp{};
    int i;

    temp = top;

    for (i = 0; i < loc - 1; i++)
    {
        prevTemp = temp;
        temp = temp->NEXT;
    }


    prevTemp->NEXT = temp->NEXT;
    free(temp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value using the wrong format specifier:

```
printf("%s %s %s %d %s\n", fileValue.ppsn, fileValue.name, fileValue.lastName, fileValue.year, fileValue.email);
                 ^^                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             Expects integer                                                     Uses float
```

To print a `float` use `%f`

Besides that you don't protect against buffer overflow. You should do:

```
result = fscanf(inp, "%9s %29s %19s %f %29s\n", ...
```

to set a maximum of chars for each buffer.

Comment: Ok cheers for this got it working I tried with the float but this just resulted in 0.001 being printed instead of the year i put in so I changed year to a char instead and its working perfectly sound